# An acceleration problem with my Pulsar 150

Tags: engine, motorcycle, clutch, bajaj, pulsar

While driving long distances sometimes my bike has problems when accelerating.

It doesn't go above the speed of 40kmh - the speedo stuck at 4(max 12) even after pulling full throttle. I have to drop down the gears to maintain the pickup.

I have recently had it serviced and the guy in the service center changed the clutch plate and timing chain but still I have the same problem.

Please help me to Identify the possible reasons for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this actually a "Pulsar" scooter? What is the year of it? What is the mileage? Have you done any other maintenance on it? If so, what and when?

Comment: This may be a vacuum leak. Clean carburetor and re-install